# Named parameter query not behaving as hoped:

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2010. I'm trying to create a parameterized query. I got it to work perfectly like this:

```
WHERE PerformedBy.artists LIKE ? + '*';
```

I then tried to give the parameter a name like this:

```
WHERE PerformedBy.artists LIKE %test% + '*';
```

Which is how MSDN suggests to do it. But Access throws me a syntax error.

Any suggestions?
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't surround the parameter name with `%` characters.  If you want to enclose the name, use square brackets.

```sql
WHERE PerformedBy.artists LIKE [test] + '*';
WHERE PerformedBy.artists LIKE [test] & '*';
```

Those two used different concatenation operators.  The second will return all rows with Null supplied as the value for `[test]`.  The first will return no rows when `[test]` is Null.